# NextJS: dynamic router.pathname does not show path, but filename - how to get words in path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, single-page-application

I'm making this as simple of an example as possible, I can include more code later if it needs more info to be resolved

I'm using dynamic routes in nextJS. My app pulls results from twitter based on the keywords entered into the dynamic route via API using `twitter-v2` package

I'm trying to use the words in the route using `router.pathname` in order to create some attributes on the page, but it uses the filename instead of the words in the url.

NextJS version: `Next 9.5.3`

Render page path: `/pages/[keywords].jsx`

Example url:

```
http://localhost:3000/kpop-heroes
```

example page function:

```
import Router from 'next/router'

export default function Keywords() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const KEYWORDS = router.pathname
    .slice(1)
    .split('-')
    .join(' ');

  return (
   <div>Twitter reactions to <code>{KEYWORDS}</code></div>
  )
};
```

Renders:

[image: Pathname renders filename, not words typed in URL]

Am I misunderstanding this feature? Is it possible to retrieve the words in the url instead of the filename?

Note:  I've been using `window.location.href` as a workaround, but my understanding is accessing the window object is less than optimal

Answer (score 18):

Use the `asPath` property. It returns the path shown in the browser (including the query).

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object

```js
const router = useRouter();

router.asPath
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, router.asPath will resolve all the dynamic parts of the url

Comment: In my case I was using router.asPath in a useEffect and it wouldn't resolve the dynamic parts, so I had to add  router.isReady in the dependency array and check for it in the useEffect callback.

Answer (score 5):

To get correct URL for both cases e.g. dynamic (`[slug]`) and fixed path:

```
const router = useRouter();

let relativeURL = "";

  const slug = router.query.slug;
  if (slug) {
    relativeURL = router.pathname.replace("[slug]", slug as string);
  } else {
    relativeURL = router.pathname;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I was just using the wrong method - the correct method is `router.query`.

Consider the following url:

```
http://localhost:3000/test-keywords?query=params,%20strings,%20other%20things&anotherLevel=more%20stuff
```

log the object produced by the method:

```
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log(router.query);
```

output:

```
  {
    anotherLevel: "more stuff"
    keywords: "test-keywords"
    query: "params, strings, other things"
  }
```

I must've glossed over it, it's clearly in the docs right here:  https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Thought I'd leave this up in case someone else confused about it, too

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way is define the [dynamic-routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) under a specific `path` (ex. /twitter).

Render page path:

```
/pages/twitter/[keywords].jsx
```

Example url:

```
http://localhost:3000/twitter/kpop-heroes
```

It is unreasonable to define the dynamic-route at the first level of the url.

Comment: I've been using the first level just fine (?).  I don't think it matters if it's in a subdir.  Under 'caveats' https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes says: Predefined routes take precedence over dynamic routes, and dynamic routes over catch all routes. I personally just have index.jsx in the pages dir, and anything else defaults to [keywords].jsx

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
```

...

```
const router = useRouter();
const path = router.asPath.split("?")[0]; // (remove query string and use asPath since dynamic slug was rendering as "[slug]" using pathname)
```

...

```
 const navigationList = (
    <MenuList>
      {links.map((item) => {    
        return (
          <MenuItem
            key={item.id}
            disabled={path == item.href}
            sx={{
              m: 0,
              p: 0,
              ...(path == item.href && {
                borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.palette.primary.light}`,
                backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
              }),
            }}
          >
            <StyledLink href={item.href}>{item.label}</StyledLink>
          </MenuItem>
        );
      })}
    </MenuList>
  );
```